# Reading Sqlite Cursor carsh on Android 4.2 API 17

Tags: android, sqlite

I have  a table with *145* rows. when i try to get all of it's data it getting *crashed* on `android 4.2`, **BUT** it works fine on `android 4.4 emulator`.

```
public ArrayList<QuestionInfoHolder> getAllArticle()
    {
        ArrayList<QuestionInfoHolder> result = new ArrayList<QuestionInfoHolder>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + ARTICLE_TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY "+ QUESTION_DATE +";";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if(cursor != null)
        {
            for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext())
            {
                result.add(new QuestionInfoHolder(cursor.getInt(0),
                        cursor.getInt(1),
                        cursor.getString(2),
                        cursor.getString(3),
                        cursor.getString(4)));
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

the logcat:

```
Failed to read row 9, column 0 from a CursorWindow which has 9 rows, 5 columns.
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 9, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

this says the cursor has only 9 rows, but if i log `cursor.getCount();` it will show `145`.

i can not figure out what is the problem. so any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

UPDATE 1:

`DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);` log:

```
I/System.out: 99 {
E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 9, column 0 from a CursorWindow which has 9 rows, 5 columns.
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b5e9a8)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 9, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.dumpCurrentRow(DatabaseUtils.java:562)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(DatabaseUtils.java:499)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(DatabaseUtils.java:482)
```

Comment: use `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor` do see your `Cursor` BTW why are you iterating over the whole `Cursor` and adding its content to the `ArrayList` ?

Comment: ok, i used `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor` and the crash happens at row 99 `I/System.out: 99 { Failed to read row 9, column 0 from a CursorWindow which has 9 rows, 5 columns.`. for your second question, i need to use this data in a custom RecyclerView Adapter so i create a ArrayList of them. is there a better way?

Comment: wait, `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor` crashes? for a better way: https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b

Comment: yes, it crashes. see update 1 in question.

Comment: do you store any huge data in your table or just strings like "one", "two", "three" ?

Comment: the `Content` column has almost more than 200 line of html code. so yes, there is huge data.

Comment: so for testing  remove that column and try again

Comment: you mean remove it completely from database? or just replace `cursor.getString(4)` with `""` ?   - Content is 5th column-

Comment: first you could try not to read the column 4 and replace cursor.getString(4) with "", if the result is the same, try to update your db with empty string in column `Content`

Comment: ok, i replaced `cursor.getString(4)` with `""` and same crash happened again.

Comment: so update your db then

Comment: ok, i removed the `Content` column and the crash gone. so how can i deal with this?

Comment: see the original @laalto answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33460499/revisions

Comment: yep, i saw that, but i'm not sure how can this solve my problem.

Comment: do you need that html `Content` column to be shown in the `RecyclerView` ???

Comment: i just need a limited amount like 200 char in RecyclerView, But i need all of it elsewhere. i have 50KB html in row 100. i tried to get just this row and it getting crashed again.

Comment: then either keep it in external text file or `java.util.zip.ZipFile` or try to reduce its size: maybe simple replacing multiple tabs/spaces would be enough, maybe `java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream` / `java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream` ? you need to try

Comment: or maybe [snappy](https://github.com/xerial/snappy-java) ?

Comment: you mean compressing data then put it in database? or ? the database is not mine so i can not store this column in a separate file.

Comment: what do you mean `not mine`? if you cannot change its structure then try: `SQLiteDatabase#compileStatement`

Comment: tnx for your help, you help me find the problem. finally i used `sqlite4java` for database handling :)

Comment: you dont need it at all, you can just read your `Content` data with `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement`

Comment: You said that in your previous comment, i searched and reached that lib:) ok, i will try the android `SQLiteStatement`. Tnx anyway.

Comment: `stm = db.compileStatement("select Content from Articles where _id = ?");` then call `stm.bindLong(1, ...)` and finaly `stm.simpleQueryForString()`

Comment: what is the `stm.bindLong(1, ...)`, i can not find any example to get all row. is this just for getting `1 * 1` data?

Comment: yes, one to one, the other columns are in the `Cursor`, no need to read them using `SQLiteStatement`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Underlying Android `CursorWindow` is limited to 2MB of data. Attempting to work with a `Cursor` that has more data than that will cause these "failed to read" exceptions.

You can work around it by not including columns with large data in your query. Replace the `SELECT *` with a more selective `SELECT column1,column2,...` without any large data columns.

Overall you should not store any large data such as images or file content in an Android sqlite database. Store the large data in the filesystem and just store the path in your database.

Comment: `CursorWindow` limit is different with API version? this code works fine on android 4.4 . the large data is just an html text with almost 20KB size. i need all column data. do you suggest getting data one column at a time?

Comment: your original answer was right, not updated one, note the `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor` crashes as well

Comment: please look at my question again, there is 145 rows in the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Read The Cursor in this way

```
   if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

              result.add(new QuestionInfoHolder(cursor.getInt(0),
                    cursor.getInt(1),
                    cursor.getString(2),
                    cursor.getString(3),
                    cursor.getString(4)));

            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

with the help from @pskink i finally reached this code that can retrieve all data without any error. tnx everybody.

```
ArrayList<QuestionInfoHolder> result = new ArrayList<QuestionInfoHolder>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement st = db.compileStatement("SELECT Content FROM " + ARTICLES_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE ID = ?;");
        String query = "SELECT ID,CategoryID,Title,Date FROM " + ARTICLES_TABLE_NAME +";";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if(cursor != null)
        {
            for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext())
            {
                st.bindLong(1, cursor.getInt(0));
                String content = st.simpleQueryForString();
                result.add(new QuestionInfoHolder(cursor.getInt(0),
                        cursor.getInt(1),
                        cursor.getString(2),
                        cursor.getString(3),
                        content));
            }
        }
```