# I can't insert high resolution Image

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm working on [this](https://github.com/quocnguyenvan/food-sqlite-demo) project and I have a problem. If I select a high resolution (ex:2 MB) image application is crashing. How can I solved this problem?

My sqlite table:

Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR, price VARCHAR, image BLOB

Image Insert Code:

```
  public static byte[] imageViewToByte(ImageView image) {
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    return byteArray;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY){
        if(grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bu dosyaya erişiminiz yok !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return;
    }

    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

FoodList.java get data codes:

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.food_list_activity);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new FoodListAdapter(this, R.layout.food_items, list);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // get all data from sqlite
    Cursor cursor = MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM FOOD");
    list.clear();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(0);
        String name = cursor.getString(1);
        String price = cursor.getString(2);
        byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(3);

        list.add(new Food(name, price, image, id));
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Error Log :

If I want to see image list : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjQlD.png)

Comment: show the error log please

Comment: I added, you can see.

Comment: Android studio error log I meant, the image u posted that is run time error on the system, that doesnt help me analyze the issue.

Comment: I'm Sorry my bad, I fixed it.

Comment: I see the error log, which is the line 57 of FoodList.class here in ur mentioned code ?

Comment: // get all data from sqlite
        Cursor cursor = MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM FOOD");
        list.clear();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int id = cursor.getInt(0);
            String name = cursor.getString(1);
            String price = cursor.getString(2);
            byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(3);

            list.add(new Food(name, price, image, id));
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I dont think you understand the issue, the error log clearly states your issue is in FoodList class, you should post the code of FOodList class here, I dont think issue is with 2MB image..  please know the error and post relevant code to the error so people can help you..

Comment: Okay I added list codes, thanks.

Comment: It seems you are not creating databse properly as your error says couldnt find row 0 and column 0.. check your db helper class

Comment: You cannot move data larger than 2MB thru Android Cursor. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459784/reading-sqlite-cursor-carsh-on-android-4-2-api-17

Comment: I can't solved.